# Flutter - GridView & StreamBuilder with Firebase Realtime DB

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, gridview, stream-builder

I'm trying to learn about how can I insert my Image URLs -which are stored in my Firebase Realtime DB as `image_cat` key's value as string type- to GridView.

My DB structuse is like:

```
{
  "Products": {
    "Baby": {
      "image_cat": "https://url1.com"
    },
    "Beauty": {
      "image_cat": "https://url2.com"
    },
    "Grocery": {
      "image_cat": "https://url3.com"
    }
  }
}
```

I've written a code like this;

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String idScreen = "myScreen";

  @override
  _MyScreenState createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {

  final database = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("Products");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mainuserlist = database.onValue;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(children: [
          Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder<DatabaseEvent>(
                stream: mainuserlist,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    final myuser = snapshot.data!.snapshot;
                     myuser.children.forEach((element) {
                       element.children.forEach((element2) {
                         if(element2.key == "image_cat"){
                           print(element2.value); // HERE I CAN GET MY WHOLE IMAGE URLS
                         }
                       });
                    });
                    return GridView.builder(
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                            mainAxisExtent: 200,
                            maxCrossAxisExtent: 150,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 5,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 5),
                        itemCount: 10,
                        itemBuilder: (context, count) {
                          return Transform(
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: 80,
                              height: 80,
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: 25,
                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage("?") // I NEED TO USE IN HERE
                              ),
                            ),
                            transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(-0.2),
                            alignment: FractionalOffset.centerRight,
                          );
                        });
                  }
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As I shown with forEach in the code, I can get my whole URLs one by one. But I don't know how can I insert them in to GridView. I need to use them in my NetworkImage widget.

1)How can I do that?
2)Also, is there any way to prevent to use 2 forEach? or any more better performanced way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a List and add each Image-URL to it, and use it in the `GridView.builder`

like this:

```
List images = [];
final myuser = snapshot.data!.snapshot;

myuser.children.forEach((element) {
    element.children.forEach((element2) {
        if(element2.key == "image_cat"){
            images.add(element2.value);
        }
    });
});
```

and to use them in the `GridView.builder` you need to specify the itemCount as the images list length, and u can access each item in the list by the index that is provided by the `GridView.builder`:

```
GridView.builder(
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
        
        itemCount: images.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, count) {
            return Transform(
                child: SizedBox(
                    width: 80,
                    height: 80,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 25,
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(images[count]) // I NEED TO USE IN HERE
                    ),
                ),
                transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(-0.2),
                alignment: FractionalOffset.centerRight,
            );
        }
    );
)
```